# Window resize width not working correctly jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using the following code to activate a jQuery function that will hide the top bar when scrolled past 800 width. The issue I'm having is that this will ONLY activate when it is made smaller from desktop size and it will then continue to work on a width larger than 800 when it's moved back to desktop size. How can I make this work on ONLY the width I've chosen and then either stop / start working.

Edit. To clarify, it works when the page is made SMALLER from the desktop size, then it will work back up until it passes 800 again, in which case it'll end up working for desktop + larger sizes. Go back down and it will have stopped working. We need this to fire once and stop working when it goes above and only fire when the width is passed which is what I thought was happening in my code!

```
function toggleBar(){
        var mywindow = $(window);
        var mypos = mywindow.scrollTop();
        var up = false;
        var newscroll;
        mywindow.scroll(function () {
            newscroll = mywindow.scrollTop();
            if (newscroll > mypos && !up) {
                $('header#header-top').stop().slideToggle();
                up = !up;
                console.log(up);
            } else if(newscroll < mypos && up) {
                $('header#header-top').stop().slideToggle();
                up = !up;
            }
            mypos = newscroll;
            });
```

and in my document load.

```
 $(window).resize(function() {
                var pageWidth = $(window).width(); 
                if ($(window).width() < 800){
                    toggleBar();
                    $('#header#header-top').attr('href','../css/main.css');
                }

            });
```

Comment: try triggering the resize: `}).resize();`.

Comment: this still doesn't work, as when it is made bigger it will then begin to work on widths above what I stated, then when it's brought back down it will no longer work on my responsive versions.

Answer (score 0):

1. on your code, you appeared to be missing an ')' for your toggleBar, I assume that's just a typo, but wanted to check.
2. I created a quick jsfiddle and it works just as you expect. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/987815za/)

Which leaves me think that either you have code elsewhere which is somehow messing everything up OR your browser is messing up.

Try using `document.body.scrollTop = 0;` instead of ScrollTop as that isn't supported by all browsers.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Unfortunately document.body doesn't work and when I change it back to scrollTop it still doesn't work properly, removing the bar on full screen and then when being moved back down then no longer removes the bar. It must be a cause of something else in the code but I've inherited a 1000 line js file!

Comment: ouch, 1000 lines.. do you get any errors in the console when you shrink then re-expand?

Comment: No errors unfortunately. I think I need to find an alternative to the code toggling as it does not seem to work properly when passing the 800 mark, it will switch on and off as to whether the functionality works